# File Upload using observables Angular 2, Get Url of the uploaded file

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload

I am uploading images to Nodejs server using Angular 2 HTTPRequest class and tracking progress of upload as well. Once the upload is completed I return the path of the uploaded file in response to the POST request. I am stuck with/unable to capture the return value of the post request. I need the URL to show a thumbnail of the image just uploaded.

The below snippet is from Nodejs.

```
router.post('/',function(req, res, next) {
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
var oldPath;
var newPath;
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

    for(var file in files) {
        if(!files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
            continue;
        }

        oldPath = files[file].path;
        newPath = './uploadedFiles/' + files[file].name;
        fs.renameSync(oldPath, newPath);           
    }
    res.json(newPath);
    res.end();
});
module.exports = router;
```

The below snippet is from Angular 2 on client side.

```
uploadFiles(f, progressUpdate) {
    this.files = f;
    let req: any;
    const data = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        data.append('file' + i, this.files[i], this.files[i].name);
    }
    req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'api/upload', data, {
        reportProgress: true
    });
// The `HttpClient.request` API produces a raw event stream
// which includes start (sent), progress, and response events.
return this.http.request(req).pipe(
  map(event => this.getEventMessage(event, this.files[0])),
  tap(message => progressUpdate(message)),
  last()
);
}
```

Comment: Are you saving the file in a database or in a directory?
Can we see that part of the code?

Comment: I am saving it to a folder on the server.

Comment: So use a callback or a promise to wait on the file save completion, standardize the file name, and return the predefined path.
Can you make that part of your code available?

Comment: Specifically I am struggling with the client side code. How to get to the value returned by the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so figured it out myself...There was an HttpEvent being fired called the EventType.Response. This had an event object where a body property contained the response I was returning from the server...My bad...